# Client Side Validation applied to fields which are dynamically available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

Ok I have been trying to find an answer on this for a couple of days unsuccessfully (with a few poorly worded questions along the way). So if you know of where an answer to this has already been discussed please point it out to me.

Here is my issue;
 I am working with a form that is built with kendo (i did not create it, and this is my first time working with kendo). part of the design calls for 2 or more optional fields that only appear when a criteria is met. For example if someone selects "2 part combo" or "3 part combo" in a drop down menu then the appropriate number of additional drop down items appear for the user to define the different parts of their combo. now those extra drop downs exist all the time on the page and simply get switched between being visible or hidden.
however when they are hidden their value is also null.

I need to have these fields validate as required ONLY when they are visible and not validate when they are not.

here is a sample of the code where it determines if the field is visible or hidden

```
    @model PhoenixOnlineMVC.Areas.EventManagement.Models.CompetitionPlannedElementItem
<script type="text/javascript">
@Html.Raw(Model.Code)
</script>
<tr style="vertical-align: top;">
<td>@Model.Index</td>
<td>@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTypeId)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:120px" })
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .BindTo(Model.Types)
          )</td>
<td>@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedElementId)
           .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:160px" })
           .DataTextField("Text")
           .DataValueField("Value")
           .Events(events => events.Select(@Model.SelectedFunctionName))
           .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetCascadeElements", "Event")
                                                           .Data(@Model.DataFunctionName))
                                        .ServerFiltering(true))
           .Enable(false)
           .AutoBind(false)
           .CascadeFrom(@Model.TypeComboBoxName)
           )</td>
<td style="width: 130px; overflow: auto">
    @{
              const string htmlHiddenAttributes = "width:120px; margin: 2px 4px 4px 0; display:none; ";
              const string htmlVisibleAttributes = "width:120px; margin: 2px 4px 4px 0;";

              if (Model.SelectedSuppElementId1 != null) 
                  { 
                      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSuppElementId1, Model.SuppElements1, new { style = htmlVisibleAttributes })
                  }
              else
                  {
                      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSuppElementId1, Model.SuppElements1, new { style = htmlHiddenAttributes })
                  }
```

this code comes from a .cshtml file that is used by the main view for the page to create the components. and all of it is contained within an Html.BeginForm on the main page.

the above code is used to create an instance of the SelectedSuppElementId fields multiple times in the main view page

If you don't have a suggestion for a solution perhaps point me to additional helpful information

Comment: I have decide to go a different route with this one so this question is no longer relevant

Answer (score 0):

Would this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/pEdaE/46/) help you any?

It just looks at the css attribute display and tells you if the element is displayed or hidden.

JS

```
$('.hide').on('click', function(){
    $('.hideme').hide();
});
$('.show').on('click', function(){
    $('.hideme').show();
});
$('.validate').on('click', function(){
    $('.putmehere').html('');
    $('.dropdown').each(function(){ 
        if( $(this).css('display') == 'none' )
       {
         $('.putmehere').append('hidden ');
        }
         else
         {
         $('.putmehere').append('shown '); 
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, no that is not what I am dealing with.
best way i can describe is a series of cascading drop down lists. so list1 dictates what is on list2 and if certain options are selected on list2 some of those hidden fields become visible.  on top of that there are multiple instances of this in a single form

Comment: I have gotten permission from my boss to redesign the part of this that is giving so many problems so this question is no longer relevant. thanks for the help